# Advanced Data Compression

Tags: compression

My problem is related to data compression: I have 17 bytes of data and each byte has 5 bits of data and 3 unused bits. So I can't figure out: how do I compress this data such that the remaining 3 bits are filled from byte number 0, so that a few of the bytes towards the end become unused and hence reduce space. Any ideas to proceed? Please note: A small chunk of code would also be helpful.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Is this a school / university assignment? Did you try anything yet? And what is the exact requirement - just compress all the "fivers" in 11 bytes, or do you also need access methods?

Comment: If this is a school / university assignment, they probably want you to learn about bit and/or, and bit shifting, and you should really learn these. Of course there's also a lazy way with java: use MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.writeBits() and ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: What code have you tried?